# How to filter by multiple event_params in BQ for GA4 events

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have GA4 data in BigQuery and I am aware I can use *unnest* to select values from the event_params. However, I dont know how to filter based on multiple values (e.g. dimensions) at the same time. For instance I have two dimensions called page_path and previous_page_path which I can select individually by

```sql
SELECT 
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_path') AS page_path,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'previous_page_path') AS previous_page_path,
FROM `project.dataset.events_*`
```

But when I try to add a *Where* now to do additional filtering the alias names do not get resolved and BigQuery returns an error. The following for example does not work:

```sql
SELECT 
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_path') AS page_path,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'previous_page_path') AS previous_page_path,
FROM `project.dataset.events_*`
WHERE page_path = "/"
```

How can this be done?

In the end I want to be able to filter for multiple event_params. I am pretty sure it requires multiple unnesting steps since key can not have two values at the same time but I do not know as to how exactly the query needs to look like to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used GA4 data in BigQuery public dataset to demonstrate the query.
Assuming you want to filter the data based on the values of 2 dimensions:

- key : `page_title`, value : `Home`
- key : `session_engaged`, value : `1`

you can consider below.

```sql
SELECT (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_title') AS page_title,
       (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'session_engaged') AS session_engaged,
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_20210131`
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(event_params) e 
         WHERE (key, value.string_value) IN (('page_title', 'Home'), ('session_engaged', '1'))
       ) = 2;

-- Query results
+------------+-----------------+
| page_title | session_engaged |
+------------+-----------------+
| Home       |               1 |
| Home       |               1 |
| Home       |               1 |
+------------+-----------------+
```

- `Where` clause returns `true` only when found both dimensions at the same time. (I assumed that each dimension isn't duplicate in the `event_params` in a row)

Comment: This is actually pretty cool! But I guess there is no way to have it more dynamic like doing comparisons with Like or number comparisons with greater or smaller than right? It is just straight string matches fully right? Still pretty nice though

Comment: Above condition is based on an exact string match of key-value pair.  But under some assumption you can use other way like a regular expression as well. For example, if the value `Home`  belongs to only key `page_title` and you want to filter the data only this key-value pair,  you can use `WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(FORMAT('%t', event_params), r'Home')` without *UNNEST*ing the array.

Comment: For anyone that was confused by the `COUNT(1)` in the final WHERE clause like I was, the number you put in the function is arbitrary.. `COUNT(1)` is pretty much going to return the number of records you find.

This link helped: https://www.dbblogger.com/post/difference-between-sql-count-count-1-count-column_name-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same logic (before the alias in WHERE clause as well).

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_path') = "/"
```

You could also use CTE:

```
WITH myBaseQuery AS (
  <insert your original query>
)

SELECT * FROM myBaseQuery WHERE page_path = "/"
```